# Filter RE in grep

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

The command that I have is:

```
grep -E '^  [0..9]'
```

The pattern that I have

```
  24
    -38.54270131
  24
    -38.54085331
  24
    -38.53603119
  24
    -38.53427780
  24
    -38.53396521
  24
    -38.53226876
  24
    -38.53211376
```

Expected output:

```
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
```

Comment: `[0..9]` matches a single character `0`, `.`, or `9` - what is your intent?

Comment: Also, you haven't explained your filtering criteria. In your example, the lines that have the number `24` have 2 spaces first, and the other lines have 4 spaces, then a `-` sign. So is the criteria to filter out all lines starting with 4 spaces and a `-`?

Comment: ... obligatory [Now you have two problems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems)

Comment: We really can't help if you don't tell us what we are supposed to look for. Please [edit] and write out exactly what you want to filter. If you want to match all lines that start with _exactly two_ spaces and then have _at least one number_, then tell us that. If you want two or more spaces and exactly two numbers, tell us that. Unless you explain what you really want, we cannot give you the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

With [AWK](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/awk.1posix.html):

```
awk '/^[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+$/' file
```

... will print lines that start `^` with `[[:blank:]]` (space and tab) once or more `+`<sup>1</sup> followed by `[[:digit:]]` (numbers in any form UNICODE included) once or more `+` followed by the end of the line `$`.

<sub>1) *use the `*` quantifier instead to match zero or more `[[:blank:]]` ... This will **also** allow matching lines containing only `[[:digit:]]`*</sub>

Demonstration:

```
$ cat file
  24
    -38.54270131
  24
    -38.54085331
  24
    -38.53603119
  24
    -38.53427780
  24
    -38.53396521
  24
    -38.53226876
  24
    -38.53211376
$ 
$ 
$ awk '/^[[:blank:]]+[[:digit:]]+$/' file
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
  24
$
```

Comment: it might be worth pointing out that the same regex (minus the `/` delimiters) would work equally well with `grep -E` (since that appears to be what the OP is focused on)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't explain your filtering criteria in any meaningful way. Here are a couple of RegEx solutions that will give the desired output:

Match any line with 2 spaces at line start, then 2 digits followed by EOL:

```
grep -E '^ {2}[0-9]{2}$'
```

Match any line that *does not* contain 4 spaces at line start, then a `-`:

```
grep -vE '^ {4}-'
```

If this does not work for you, please be explicit in your filter criteria.